# Map.ofSeq performance breakdown

Tags: performance, dictionary, collections, f#

While streaming a 450 MB / 6.6 Mio records file from Zip format on disk into memory as a sequence works with adequate performance, but turning that sequence into a map via `Map.ofSeq` seems to be practically impossible:

```
    // within a let binding ...
    getPart fileName xPath partUri
    |> fun x -> printfn " getPart finished, parsing ..." ; x |> Seq.map (fun x -> 
        let test name = 
            let x' = (xd x).Root.Descendants() |> Seq.filter (fun x'' -> x''
            // do some System.Xml.Linq stuff here)
    |> fun x -> printfn " Parsing finished,  reorg seq ..." ; x |> Seq.map (fun x -> x.Reference, x )
    |> fun x -> printfn " Reorg finished,  building cell map...   ### see this ###  " ; x |> Map.ofSeq

do printfn "%s" " ### never see this ### done, now building keys..."
```

Is this a known issue or am I making a mistake?

Comment: `Seq` is `IEnumerable` - so it's lazy. `Map.ofSeq` - is not lazy so it's trying to enumerate over all members of sequence - hence performance hit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Petr mentioned in the comment, the `Seq` operations are lazy and so your intermediate messages get printed immediately before any work is done.

That said, if you are creating a very large lookup table, then `Map.ofSeq` is slower than other options. Here is a quick performance test using 1 million array:

```
let rnd = System.Random()
let arr = Array.init 1000000 (fun i -> rnd.Next(), i) |> Seq.distinctBy fst |> Array.ofSeq
```

Now using `#time` on my machine, I get the following numbers:

```
#time 
// 19 seconds
let m = Map.ofSeq arr

// 0.3 second
let d1 = dict arr

// 0.1 second
let d2 = System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<int, int>(arr.Length)
for k, v in arr do d.Add(k, v)
```

The main difference is that map is immutable and so you can add and remove items while keep the original value of the map. If that's what you need, then map is the best data structure.

In contrast, using `dict` creates a readonly dictionary (based on hash table) that gives you fast lookup, but cannot be modified once it is created. Finally, the third option creates an ordinary mutable hashtable.

A part of the reason why `Map.ofSeq` is slow is also the fact that the current implementation adds elements one by one and rebalances the tree (which is how data is stored) after every insert. This could be done in a more clever and faster way (which would be a nice contribution to the F# core libraries :-)).

Comment: In my particular use case, I process pieces of XML that I convert into records. The `seq` performance for that measures in ~ 1 min. The `map` does not return after more than 20 min. I use now just filtering on the `seq` for accessing the items which works quite nicely with concise syntax in my use case.

Comment: Try the `dict` function - that should tell you whether the laziness is causing the problem, or whether the fact that `Map.ofSeq` is slow is causing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I could finally verify that the observed performance breakdown was caused by the XML transformations. The involved run time counted in hours. After refactoring the XML transformations, I observe elapsed time of ~2 sec with `dict` and ~30 sec with `Map` on my data set. Refactoring included to introduce a fixed memory layout of the underlying data records. I suspect a relevant impact on performance by that but I did not measure this separately.